# the DOM doesn't work with me when I try min and max and it show NaN

Tags: javascript, dom, max, min

when I run it gave me a NaN and I have tried many times. here's the javascript file and HTML file

javascrit file:

```
function MinButton(){
    var td1Text = document.getElementById("td1").textContent;

    // Get array of numbers from text
     var OriginalArray = td1Text.split(",").map(function(num){
       return parseInt(num,10);
     });
    
    // Get td2
    var Min =  document.getElementById("MinTable");
    
    // Set td2 to sorted array converted to string
    Min.textContent = parseInt(Math.min(OriginalArray));
}
```

HTML file:

```
<tr>
            

    <th>Original array</th>
                    <!--<td><input type="text" id="textO"  size="40"></td>-->
               

         <td id ="td1">1,5,7,-1,3</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
                    <th>Sorted Array</th>
                    <td id="td2"></td>
    </tr>    
<input type="button" value="Find Min" id="Min" onclick="MinButton();">
```

Comment: [`Math.min`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) accepts individual arguments, not arrays. It’s `Math.min(...OriginalArray)`. `function(num){ return parseInt(num,10); }` can be replaced by `Number`. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%253Astackoverflow.com+js+Math.min+with+Array+results+in+NaN) of [Why is math.max() returning NaN on an array of integers?](/q/32647149/4642212).

Comment: Also, note that the `.map` can be entirely removed since `Math.min` converts each of its arguments to numbers anyway. The final `parseInt` can also be removed, as `Math.min` only returns numbers.